# interaction.client.commands.get() is undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm following [this guide to making a discord bot with discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/).

I've followed line for line and I'm getting an error that line 6 of the `interactionCreate` file is undefined and it doesn't show anything. Here's their [file from their github that I'm talking about.](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/creating-your-bot/event-handling/events/interactionCreate.js) What am I not putting in there?

Comment: you need to define commands into a collection using `client.commands = new Collection()`, without your code I can't help you more